# Matlab changing variable type, checking not making sense

Tags: matlab

I might be doing something silly or just have a lack of understanding but I am currently working with a table of data and when I change the variable type of a column using the table.column notation when I check using the table`(:,1)` notation it returns a `0`.

For example in my table the first column is `Creditability` (where table is the name of the table) so I changed the variable type using `table.Creditability = logical(table.Creditability)`

Then when I use `islogical(table.Creditability)` it returns `1`

But when I use `islogical(table(:,1))` it returns `0` yet when I type `table(:,1)` it returns a logical variable in `true` or `false` form.

I may just have a lack of understanding as I am new to this but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Initially the code table.Creditability creates a structure with the field Creditability. So if you convert table.Creditability to logical, you only convert its field, the structure is still a structure without any datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will return 0. This is because of basic point you are missing.
"table" is a structure variable in which a field named "Creditability" is created.
While "Creditability" is a logical array, it's parent "table" is still a structure.
Now, you are not getting error with statement table(:,1) although table is scalar. That is because, MATLAB treats everything as matrix. 
In this case, table is 1x1 matrix.

I hope it is clear now.